# Is it worth encrypting a password hash?

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords, sha, password-encryption

I was wondering if it is common practice to encrypt a password hash, and/or the salt, does it necessarily make it more secure or just increase the time it'd take to "guess" the password?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is pointless. The original password is already unrecoverable after the hashing step. And if your system allows any kind of access to either the hashed or the encrypted-hashed password you have far bigger problems than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not common practice to encrypt a salted hash. It may slightly increase security but realistically it's not worth it, since you'd have to manage the key in some way, complicating the whole process. Using a salted hash with a secure hashing algorithm will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't need to encrypt hash as long as you use good cryptographic hash function. As for salt, salting is done best before encrypting, ie. salt does get encrypted. The exception would be one-time table, in which case you can easily salt afterwards. As for the third question, whole encryption is nothing but increasing the time it takes to "guess" the plaintext, exception being again one-time table. Now what's your concrete problem? Can you formulate it as a task in some concrete computer language?

Comment: Eh? Don't need to use encryption but you do need to use salting before encryption?

Answer (score 1):

If the hash was produced by a "good" algorithm, than it doesn't make any sense to cipher it, since you would be essentially ciphering something that in theory only the rightful user can generate.

Ciphering the salt doesn't add any kind of real security.